# Unable to write to asp.net textbox control with the html5 "date" type

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, .net-4.0

I have an asp.net page with a an html5 TextBox control set as the "date" type. The control on my page looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxMyDate" runat="server" type="date"/>
```

It works great in the page and I can click on it and set the date. I can also read the date through TextBoxMyDate.Text. However, I cannot figure out how to programaticaly set the date. I have tried various formats of:

`TextBoxMyDate.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
TextBoxMyDate.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

My guess is that its much more complicated than simply setting the text value but I don't know where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually the correct way to set the date but the format was wrong!

```
TextBoxMyDate.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I was confusing how the browser displays the date and the html5 standards for this control!

Comment: Man! I was about to go crazy. I was trying "yyyy-mm-dd". Didn't know the 'mm' should be upcase :/ TY!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is quite possible. Here is an example of a date selection filter with ajaxcontrotoolkit and the textbox field.

Overview:[calendar ajaxControlToolkit Overview](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar.ashx)

Tutorial:[Tutorial ajaxControlTollkit Date textbox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_Calendar_Simple.ashx)

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">  
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>  

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:CalendarExtender   
    ID="CalendarExtender1"   
    TargetControlID="txtStartDate"   
    runat="server" />
```