# How to set the value of a textbox textmode=date ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Please help me if you can.

I'm trying to set a textbox textmode=date from a variable.

It's like this:

```
txtDataDespesa.Text = d.DataDespesa.ToShortDateString();
```

The problem is, when I go to visualize the page, the value of `d.DataDespesa.ToShortDateString()` isn't showing in the txtDataDespesa, instead is the default values `dd/mm/yyyy`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17226535/292060

Comment: This worked for me DateTime.Parse(mydate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This has nothing to do with asp.net, but Html5. When using `type="date"` you should always use the format `yyyy-MM-dd` ([W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html#input.date.attrs.value))

The problem is that in browsers that don't support type=date, this will show up as `2014-03-30`, but on browsers that do support it, it is displayed according to the regional settings in the client OS.

So it may be `2014-03-30`, `30.March.2014` or `Mar-30-2014`, you have no control over the format, the user has.

Answer (score 17):

afaik, the new textbox in .Net with `textmode=date` only supports the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```
txtDataDespesa.Text = d.DataDespesa.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

if you need the short date string, you need to use a regular textbox.

Comment: That was a lifesaver ;) +ed :D

Answer (score 12):

```
dt_calculate_to_date.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

will work and worked

```
if !ispostback
```