# assign date to TextBox textmode="date" using code

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

when i assign the date to textBox of textmode= "date" ,it doesn't display and displays "mm/dd/yyy" although the textBox has the correct date in debugging and autopostBack is enabled  .

```
DataTable dt= DepartMentDB.GetDepartmentById(ddlDepartment.SelectedValue.ToString());
string Managername = dt.Rows[0]["Dept_Manager"].ToString();
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Manager_hiredate"].ToString());
txtHiredate.Text = d.ToString("mm/dd/yyy");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your value to DateTime object

Answer (score 2):

You want `"MM/dd/yyy"` (notice the capital M. otherwise it would convert to minutes once its working). If it's still not working, use an invariant culture to force the conversion (since you are specifying the format directly). i.e.:

```
txtHiredate.Text = d.ToString("MM/dd/yyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**EDIT:** Actually, it is because the textmode of date only support a specific format. Mainly `yyyy-MM-dd` or whatever the user specified in their culture settings. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747762/3419825

So either work with the text mode and go with yyyy-MM-dd, or remove the textmode, or use a framework like jQuery to add a mask