# set date on textbox whose mode is date

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is source code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>

 string date = read["DateOfBirth"].ToString();
 string cDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
 txtDOB.Text = cDate;
```

and I want to set date from my db the textbox whose mode is date , and I am unable to it with this code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745661/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-textmode-date-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks actually it helped me only then thing i had to change in code is format my format was ("MM/dd/yyyy"); but correct format is("yyyy-MM-dd") thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
read["DateOfBirth"], 
"MM/dd/yyyy", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
txtDOB.Text = date.ToString();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with getting dates on and off the page. I did not use the textmode=DATE though.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="DrdBirth" DataFormatString="{0:d}" CssClass="date dobDatePicker col-sm-3">
```

This code used to get it out

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DrdBirth.Text))
        {
            dateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(DrdBirth.Text);
        }
```

OR

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DrdBirth.Text))
        {
            dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(DrdBirth.Text);
        }
        else dateOfBirth = null;
```

And this code to put it back in

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r["drdDoB"].ToString()))
            {
                DateTime.TryParse(r["drdDoB"].ToString(), out dob);
                DrdBirth.Text = dob.ToShortDateString();
            }
```

In the bottom snippet "r" represents a row in a DataTable

I hope this works for you.