# Binding a Date to TextBox in Textmode=Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have an update panel with some gridviews being populated on postback as well as some textboxes that are populated through code and an SqlDataReader on _SelectedIndexChanged. Everything is working except for the two date textboxes that are set to TextMode=Date are not populating. I'm sure it's some formatting issue and I've searched and tried a few different things to no avail..... Thanks in advance !

P.s. edited out connection string

```
    public void ddlSO_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnString = "";
        String strQuery = "select strServiceOrderNo, strCustomerNo, strCustomerName, strCustomerAddress1, strCustomerAddress2, strCustomerAddress3, strServiceRequestDate, strServiceOrderDate, intStatusCodeID, intRepID from TServiceOrders where" +
                          " intServiceOrderID = @intServiceOrderID";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intServiceOrderID", ddlSO.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtCUSTNO.Text = sdr["strCustomerNo"].ToString();
                txtSONO.Text = sdr["strServiceOrderNo"].ToString();
                txtAddress1.Text = sdr["strCustomerAddress1"].ToString();
                txtAddress2.Text = sdr["strCustomerAddress2"].ToString();
                txtAddress3.Text = sdr["strCustomerAddress3"].ToString();
                txtDateCreated.Text = sdr["strServiceOrderDate"].ToString() ;
                txtDateDue.Text = sdr["strServiceRequestDate"].ToString();
                txtCustName.Text = sdr["strCustomerName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: Your `catch` block is not only unnecessary, it's detrimental.  You should remove it entirely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the value of a textbox textmode=date ASP.NET C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745661/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-textmode-date-asp-net-c-sharp)