# ASP.NET Date Format in IE and Chrome not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, input

I'm trying to pass a date from code behind to the UI as follows, and I get an error in Chrome.

C#

> txtDate.text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d");

ASP/HTML

> asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" TextMode="Date" runat="server"

In IE11 it looks fine, just like I want it to -> mm/dd/yyyy

In Chrome I get an error that says: The specfied value "9/20/2018" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd"

But if I change C# to the format Chrome wants, my IE11 date ends up looking wrong(or right) and Chrome textbox finally works.

C#

> txtDate.text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

Any idea how I can fix this without using 3rd party date inputs, and just using the standard HTML date inputs?

Comment: Hi, this may be a duplicate question - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745661/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-textmode-date-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the value of a textbox textmode=date ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745661/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-textbox-textmode-date-asp-net-c-sharp)