# Putting DOB from SQL result to textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I query my database for the dob of this user. However I'm making a page for them to update their profiles. I've got this textbox mode set to date. How can I set the DOB result into this textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" Width="400px" TextMode="Date">
```

this is my textbox code.

```
txtDOB.Text = drSel["dob"].ToString();
```

and this is the code im using to set the text. But its not working. drSel is my datareader and dob is my database column.

Comment: *"But it's not working."* Could you be a little more specific? Did you try to debug and inspect the result returned in your DataReader?

Comment: when the page loads up, the text box shows 'mm/dd/yyyy' instead of the actual date from the database. yes the result was correct when putting on a label. could the problem be that my results came with time as well?

Comment: Seems like others had this problem before: [Unable to write to asp.net textbox control with the html5 “date” type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17226535/205233) and [How to set the value of a textbox textmode=date ASP.NET C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22745661/205233)

Comment: Those don't seem like the code im looking for.